# How to order a reverse foreign key in Django?

Tags: python, django, sorting

We are using Django 1.4. We have class `A` which has a class `History` related to it. There can be many History objects related to any single object of `A`.

The `History` class has *foreign keys* to other classes, such as `BusinessUnit`.

I want to sort objects of `A` by the **last** history object, if any (sorted by `History.logged_at`).

I tried with `order_by('history__business_unit')`, but it doesn't work properly. Is it possible to sort like this using the database, or do we have to sort using Python? I prefer to sort using the database if possible.

Comment: What does "doesn't work properly" mean? What, exactly, happens, and how does that differ from what you expect to happen?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I think it sorts by a random History object or sorted by pk. I want to sort by the last History object according to History.logged_at (or the first one with reversed History.logged_at).

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Eventually I sorted with Python, using list.sort:

```
def human_key(key):
    parts = re.split('(\d*\.\d+|\d+)', key.lower())
    return tuple((e.swapcase() if i % 2 == 0 else float(e)) for i, e in enumerate(parts))

if (ordered in ["unregistered_business_unit", "unregistered_operational_unit", "unregistered_date"]):
    a_list = list(a_list)
    for a in a_list:
        a_history = list(a.history.all().order_by('-logged_at'))
        if (len(a_history) > 0):
            a.last_a_history = a_history[0]
        else:
            a.last_a_history = None
    if (ordered == "unregistered_business_unit"):
        a_list.sort(key=lambda a: (a.last_a_history.business_unit.description.lower() if ((a.last_a_history) and (a.last_a_history.business_unit)) else None, a.last_a_history.business_unit.identifier if ((a.last_a_history) and (a.last_a_history.business_unit)) else None, human_key(a.last_a_history.operational_unit.identifier) if ((a.last_a_history) and (a.last_a_history.operational_unit)) else None, a.mac_address), reverse=reverse_flag)
    elif (ordered == "unregistered_operational_unit"):
        a_list.sort(key=lambda a: (human_key(a.last_a_history.operational_unit.identifier) if ((a.last_a_history) and (a.last_a_history.operational_unit)) else None, a.last_a_history.business_unit.description.lower() if ((a.last_a_history) and (a.last_a_history.business_unit)) else None, a.last_a_history.business_unit.identifier if ((a.last_a_history) and (a.last_a_history.business_unit)) else None, a.mac_address), reverse=reverse_flag)
    elif (ordered == "unregistered_date"):
        a_list.sort(key=lambda a: (a.last_a_history.logged_at if (a.last_a_history) else pytz.utc.localize(datetime(MINYEAR, 1, 1)), a.mac_address), reverse=reverse_flag)
```

Answer (score 7):

You will have to annotate the maximum related date, filter for history objects where the max date equals the history's date, and order by a `business_unit` attribute. :

```
from django.db.models import Max, F

a = A.objects.annotate(last_date=Max('history_set__logged_at'))\
    .filter(history_set__logged_at=F('last_date'))\
    .order_by('history_set__business_unit__<attribute>')
```

This way, for each `A` object, you filter for the last `History` related object, and order on the associated `business_unit`. Using just `history_set__business_unit` will order by the business unit's id, so for any meaningful ordering you need to decide on which attribute of `business_unit` you want to order.

Comment: And how do I order by business unit of the last history object?

Comment: @Uri: Ah, so you want to order by the `business_unit` of the last `history` object for each `A`? If `business_unit` is indeed a foreign key, then ordering by just `'history__business_unit'` will order by `id`. If you want any meaningful ordering, you should order by an attribute of `business_unit`.

Comment: Yes, but there can be many history objects related to `A`. Each of them has a foreign key to one business unit. I want to order by the business unit of the last history object. Ordering by 'history__business_unit' is not ordering by the business unit of the last history object.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that there may be objects of `A` without any history objects, if you filter by last_date then it can be None.

Comment: I checked now your solution and it filters out 4 objects (of 68) and it doesn't sort the objects correctly.

Comment: @Uri: Then use `Q` objects for an OR query: `.filter(Q(history_set__logged_at=F('last_date')) | Q(history_set=None))`. In what way do the objects not sort correctly?

Comment: The 4 objects which were filtered out did have related history objects (but in theory there can be objects without any related history objects). The sorting was not correct because the objects were not sorted by the business unit of the last history object.

Comment: @Uri: Can you post 1) the exact query you're using, 2) the results you get and 3) your expected results?

Comment: I can't post data from our database. I used the same query you gave me but with `history__` instead of `history_set__` (because the related_name of the history object is "history"). I ordered by "history__business_unit" (to use the business unit's primary key) and the results were not sorted correctly.

Comment: By the way, we are using Django 1.4.

Comment: I'm on 1.4 as well, and my tests show the expected results. Can you post the generated SQL query? (You can use `print A.objects.filter().query`)